# Rails dinamically assign ids to elements and select them in js function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have this view where is possible to post comments and reply to them. I want to have a button - reply - and by clicking it opens the form below to add comment text and button to post.

This is what I have in my view:

```
<ul>
  <div class="comment">


  <strong><%= comment.user.name %></strong> - <%= comment.body %> <br>
  <small>Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago
<button class="comment">Reply</button>
<% if comment.user_id == current_user.id %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_comment_path(comment), class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm' %>
<% end %>
</div>


<div class="comment-form">
  <%= semantic_form_for [comment, Comment.new] do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Add a Reply", rows: 1, required: true, class: 'form-control' %><br/>
      <%= f.submit "Post", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'  %>

      <% end %>
</div>


        <%= render partial: 'comments/comment', collection: comment.comments %>


</ul>
```

And this is application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.comment-form').hide(); //Initially form wil be hidden.

 $('.comment').click(function() {
  $('.comment-form').show();//Form shows on button click

  });
});
```

First I tried to use div ids but the problem with that is that only the first comment hides the form on page load. So I changed to use classes (as in the code I posted). Now on page load forms are all closed. Problem is when I click on a button on a comment to open corresponding form all forms in all comments open.

How can I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both ids and class.

Use the class to close them initially as you are but add id like following code:

```
<button class="comment" data-comment-id="comment_<%=comment.id%>">Reply</button>
```

and then have your comment form like this

```
<div class="comment-form" id="comment_<%=comment.id%>">
```

you javascript code will become:

```
$('.comment').click(function() {
  var comment_id = "#" + $(this).attr('data-comment-id');
  $(comment_id).show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Code you suggested returns `undefined local variable or method comment_id for #<#<Class:0x007f92953f78c8>:0x007f929530e600> ` referring to `<div class="comment-form" id="comment_<%=comment_id%>">`

Comment: Note that I used "comment" for the button and "comment-form" for the form. Shouldn't last 2 lines of the js refer to comment-form_id instead of comment_id?

Comment: Changing to <div class="comment-form" id="comment_<%=comment.id%>"> makes the error disappear, at page load forms are closed but when click on reply button nothing happens.

Comment: Please try now, there were a couple of typos in the code

Comment: Working now. Thanks!